# In App Update sees the update, but can't install it

Tags: android, google-play

I use [InAppUpdater library](https://github.com/SanojPunchihewa/InAppUpdater) for Android In App Updates.

For testing I created a simple application with `versionCode 3`(before this I posted `versionCode 2` in the internal test track, but I did not see updates in my application with `versionCode 1`) and uploaded it in the Google play in a closed track(alpha version). On the Android device I installed `versionCode 2`.

Code:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private UpdateManager mUpdateManager;

    static final int REQUEST_CODE = 781;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        TextView txtCurrentVersion = findViewById(R.id.currentVersion);
        TextView txtAvailableVersion = findViewById(R.id.availableVersion);

        txtCurrentVersion.setText(String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE));

        // Initialize the Update Manager with the Activity and the Update Mode
        mUpdateManager = UpdateManager.Builder(this);

        // Callback from Available version code
        mUpdateManager.getAvailableVersionCode(code -> txtAvailableVersion.setText(String.valueOf(code)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Continue updates when resumed
        mUpdateManager.continueUpdate();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("MyTag", "Result ok! Result code: " + resultCode);
            }
            else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Log.d("MyTag", "Result canceled! Result code: " + resultCode);

            }
            else if(resultCode == ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED){
                Log.d("MyTag", "In app update failed! Result code: " + resultCode);

            }
        }
    }


    public void tryToUpdate(View view){
        mUpdateManager.mode(UpdateManagerConstant.FLEXIBLE).start();
    }

}
```

After starting, I see that current version = 2, available version = 3, so the app sees the update. Next I click the `tryToUpdate` button and see the update dialog, click "update", wait, see "An update has just been downloaded", click "restart", see installation activity, after that my application restarts and I see the old version - current version = 2, and this is the problem. Of course, I tried to manually close and open the app but I still see the old version. But if I delete the old version and manually install the new version from Google Play, then all works fine.

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: Posted a solution at https://github.com/SanojPunchihewa/InAppUpdater/issues/14 please check if it solves your problem

Comment: @sanoJ, thanks, I tried this, but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: hello @don-prog you already solve this problem ? i face same issue

Comment: @Yudikarma yes, if I can say so. Please check this issue: https://github.com/SanojPunchihewa/InAppUpdater/issues/14